# git-log missing merge commit that undid a change

Tags: git

Consider this test script.

```sh
#!/bin/sh -x

#initialize repository
rm -rf missing-merge-log
mkdir missing-merge-log
cd missing-merge-log
git init

# create files, x, y, and z
echo x > x
echo y > y
echo z > z
git add -A .
git commit -m "initial commit"

# create a branch
git branch branch

# change x and z on master
echo x2 > x
echo z2 > z
git commit -am "changed x to x2, z to z2"
git log master -- x

# change y and z on the branch
git checkout branch
echo y2 > y
echo z3 > z
git commit -am "changed y to y2, z to z3"

# merge master into branch
git merge master
# resolve z conflict
echo z23 > z
git add z
# undo changes to x during merge conflict resolution
# (imagine this was developer error)
git checkout branch -- x
git commit --no-edit

# merge branch into master
git checkout master
git merge branch

# now the x2 commit is entirely missing from the log
git log master -- x
```

We first create three files, `x`, `y`, and `z`, and create a branch named `branch`. In `master`, we commit a change to `x` and `z`, and in the branch, we commit a change to `y` and `z`.

Then, in the branch, we merge from `master`, but during merge conflict resolution, we revert the change to `x`. (For the sake of this example, imagine that this was a developer error; the developer didn't intend to reject the changes to `x`.)

Finally, back in `master`, we merge the changes from the branch.

I would expect at this point for `git log x` to show three changes: the initial commit, the change to `x` on master, and the branch commit that reverted the changes to `x`.

But instead, at the end of the script, `git log` just shows the initial commit to x, giving no indication that `x` had ever been modified! This using git version 2.22.0.

Why is `git log` doing this? Are there parameters to `git log -- x` that would show what happened here? `git log --all -- x` doesn't help.

(`git log --all` does show everything, but in real life that would show all changes to all files, including irrelevant changes to `y` and `z`, which would be too difficult to wade through.)

Comment: The last commit does not revert the changes to `x` as the file `x` is not changed at all during the merge, so it's not listed as expected. But it's still confusing that `git log -- x` prints only the initial commit. `git log --follow -- x` can list the other 2 commits, but  to my knowledge `--follow` is not designed for this case. `x` is not renamed during the process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Use `--full-history`—but you probably want more options too, so read on.

#### Long

First, many thanks for the reproducer script!  That was very useful here.

Next:

> (`git log --all` does show everything, but in real life that would show all changes to all files, including irrelevant changes to `y` and `z`, which would be too difficult to wade through.)

Yes.  But it demonstrates that there's no issue with any of the *commits;* the problem is entirely of `git log`'s making, here.  It has to do with the dreaded [**History Simplification**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_history_simplification) mode, which:

> `git log master -- x`

invokes.

#### `git log` without History Simplification

Let me add the output from:

```
git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

[("git log with help from A DOG")](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35075021/1256452), which since I did a reproduction using the script will have different hash IDs than you (or anyone else doing another repro) will have, but has the same structure, and thus lets us talk about the commits:

```
*   cc7285d (HEAD -> master, branch) Merge branch 'master' into branch
|\  
| * ad686b0 changed x to x2, z to z2
* | dcaa916 changed y to y2, z to z3
|/  
* a222cef initial commit
```

Now, a normal `git log`, without `-- x` to inspect file `x`, *does not* turn on history simplification.  Git starts at the commit you specify—for instance:

```
git log dcaa916
```

starts at `dcaa916`—or at `HEAD` if you did not specify anything.

In this case, then, `git log` starts with commit `cc7285d`.  Git shows that commit, then moves on to that commit's parent(s).  Here there are two parents—`dcaa916` and `ad686b0`—so Git places *both* commits into a [priority queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  Then it pulls one of the commits from the head of the queue.  When I try this, the one it pulls out is `dcaa916`.  (In more realistic graphs, it will by default use the one with the later committer timestamp, but having built this repository with a script, both commits have the same timestamp.)  Git shows that commit and places `dcaa916`'s parent `a222cef` into the queue.  For topological sanity, given this particular graph, the commit at the front of the queue is now always going to be `ad686b0`, so Git shows that commit and then....

Well, now, the parent of `ad686b0` is `a222cef`, but `a222cef` is already in the queue!  This is where that "for topological sanity" thing comes in.  By not showing `a222cef` too early we make sure that we don't accidentally show `a222cef` twice (among other issues).  The queue now has `a222cef` in it, and nothing else, so `git log` takes `a222cef` off the queue, shows `a222cef`, and puts `a222cef`'s parents in the queue.  In this reproducer-example there are no parents, so the queue remains empty, and `git log` can finish, and that's just what we see with a regular `git log`.  With help from A DOG, we get the graph too, and the one-line output variant.

#### `git log` with History Simplification

Git doesn't have *file* history.  The history in a repository consists of *commits*.  But `git log` will do its best to *show* a file history.  To do that, it has to synthesize one, and to do *that*, Git's authors chose to simply omit some subset of commits.  The documentation tries to explain that with a one-sentence paragraph:

> Sometimes you are only interested in parts of the history, for example the commits modifying a particular <path>. But there are two parts of *History Simplification*, one part is selecting the commits and the other is how to do it, as there are various strategies to simplify the history.

I think this one-paragraph explanation just doesn't work, but I have not yet come up with what I think is the *right* explanation, either. :-)  What they are trying to express here is this:

- Git isn't going to show you *all* the commits.  It's going to show some selected subset of commits.

  This part makes perfect sense.  We already see that even without History Simplification: Git starts with the *last* commit, the one we specify with a branch name or with `HEAD` or whatever, and then works backwards, one commit at a time, placing more than one commit at a time into its priority queue if and when necessary.

  *With* History Simplification, we still walk the commit graph using a priority queue, but for many commits, we're just not going to show the commit.  OK so far—but now Git throws in the twist that led them to write that weird paragraph.
- If Git isn't going to show you all commits, maybe it can *cheat* and not even bother to *follow* some forks.

  This is the hard part to express.  When we work backwards from branch-tip towards the commit-graph root, every *merge* commit, where two streams of commits join up, becomes a fork, where two streams of commits diverge.  In particular, commit `cc7285d` is a merge, and when we *don't* have History Simplification happening, Git always puts both parents into the queue.  But when we *do* have History Simplification happening, Git sometimes *doesn't* put these commits into the queue.

The really tricky part here is deciding *which* commits get into the queue, and that's where the documentation's "more detailed explanation" and *TREESAME* notion come in.  I encourage people to read through it, because it has a lot of good information, but it's very densely packed and is not very good at *defining* TREESAME in the first place.  The documentation puts it this way:

> Suppose you specified `foo` as the <paths>. We shall call commits that modify `foo` !TREESAME, and the rest TREESAME. (In a diff filtered for `foo`, they look different and equal, respectively.)

This definition *depends* on the commit being a non-merge commit!

All commits are snapshots (or more correctly, *contain* snapshots).  So no commit, taken on its own, modifies *any* file.  It just *has* the file, or doesn't have the file.  If it has the file, it has some particular content *for* the file.  To view a commit as a change—as a set of modifications—we need to pick some *other* commit, extract *both* commits, and then compare the two.  For non-merge commits, there's an obvious commit to use: the parent.  Given some chain of commits:

```
...--F--G--H--...
```

we'll see what's *changed* in commit `H` by extracting both `G` and `H`, and comparing them.  We'll see what's *changed* in `G` by extracting `F` and `G`, and comparing them.  That's what the TREESAME paragraph here is about: we take `F` and `G`, say, and strip out all but the files you asked about.  Then we compare the remaining files.  Are they the same in the stripped-down `F` and `G`?  If so, `F` and `G` are TREESAME.  If not, they're not.

But merge commits have, by definition, at least *two* parents:

```
...--K
      \
       M
      /
...--L
```

If we're at merge commit `M`, which parent do we pick to determine what's TREESAME and what's not?

Git's answer is to compare the commit to *all* of the parents, one at a time.  Some comparisons may result in "is TREESAME", and others may result in "is not TREESAME".  For instance, file `foo` in `M` may match file `foo` in `K` and/or file `foo` in `L`.

Which commits Git uses depend on the additional options you supply to `git log`:

> **Default mode**
>
> Commits are included if they are not TREESAME to any parent (though this can be changed, see `--sparse` below). If the commit was a merge, and it was TREESAME to one parent, follow only that parent. (Even if there are several TREESAME parents, follow only one of them.) Otherwise, follow all parents.

So let's consider merge `cc7285d`, and compare it to each of its (two) parents:

```
$ git diff --name-status cc7285d^1 cc7285d
M       z
$ git diff --name-status cc7285d^2 cc7285d
M       x
M       y
M       z
```

This means that `git log` will walk only the *first* parent, commit `cc7285d^1` (which is `dcaa916`)—this is the one that *doesn't* change `x`:

> ... If the commit was a merge, and it was TREESAME to one parent, follow only that parent. ...

So *this* `git log` walks commit `cc7285d`, then commit `dcaa916`, then commit `a222cef`, and then stops.  It never looks at commit `cc7285d^2` (which is `ad686b0`) at all.

The rest of this section of the `git log` documentation describes the options `--full-history`, `--dense`, `--sparse`, and `--simplify-merges` (and even I don't understand the true purpose of the last option :-) ).  Of all of these, `--full-history` is the most obvious and will do what you want.  (`--ancestry-path` and `--simplify-by-decoration` are this section as well but they don't affect paths at merges.)

#### Caveats

While `--full-history` will make sure that Git walks through all "legs" of each merge, `git log -p` itself by default shows *no* diffs for merge commits.  You must add one of three options—`-c`, `--cc`, or `-m`—to make `git log -p` show any diff at all for any merge.

If your goal is specifically to find a *bad* two-parent merge, one that drops some particular change that should have been retained, you probably want to show the diff from that merge to at least one, and perhaps both, of its two parents.  The `git show` command will do this, but its default is `--cc` style.  The `git log` command won't do it at all.  If you add `--cc` to your `git log`, you'll get the same diff that `git show` would show by default—and that's not going to work either.

The `--cc` or `-c` options tell Git that, when looking at a merge commit, Git should diff the commit against all the parents, then produce a *summary* diff, rather than a detailed one.  The contents of the summary exclude parts that match one or all parents.  You're looking for a merge that accidentally dropped an important change—a merge that is the *same* as at least one of its parents, when it should be *different* from that parent.  This combined diff is going to *hide* the place where the change isn't-but-should-be.  So you *don't* want `-c` or `--cc`.

That leaves the `-m` option.  When `git show` or `git log` is going to show a diff, and the commit is a merge commit, Git will show *one diff per parent*.  That is, for a merge commit like `M`, `git show -m` will first compare `K` vs `M` and show that diff.  Then it will compare `L` vs `M` and show the other diff.  *That's* the option you want here, for this particular case.

Note that `-m` combines nicely with `--first-parent` to show only the full diff against the first parent of each merge.  Often that's *exactly* what you want.